# Flink unable to restore operator state for a kafka consumer when starting from checkpoint

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a Streaming Job that has 20 separate pipelines, with each pipeline having one/many Kafka topic sources.

We are noticing strange behavior in restoring Operatorstate from the checkpoint when we restart the job with a new jar (I have added one more pipeline) and AllowNonRestoredState=true.

- our current config for adding pipeline is static and we are basically making code changes to add any new pipeline.
- we have not set any UID for any of the Operators.
- when we restart the pipeline with the same jar from the checkpoint we see that it restores all the operator states without any Missing state.
- we maintain parallelism of 1 for all the operators.
- some of the source operators for Kafka are not able to restore their Operator state with log `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase [] - Consumer subtask 0 has no restore state.`
  due to this Kafka consumer offset is being set to EARLIEST for all the partitions.

Flink Version:1.13.0

Is this a known issue in Flink?

Note- In some cases, we have the same topic in two pipelines with a different group.
As Per My Understanding, this should not impact any state restoration since Kafka Union state is on each Kafka consumer source for a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't explicitly provided UIDs for the operators, you are relying on automatically generated UIDs. These are only stable so long as the job's topology remains unchanged. When you add a new pipeline, this may change some or all of the previously auto-generated UIDs, and make that state unrestorable.

If you want to ensure you will be able to restore state, set UIDs on all stateful operators. See Flink's [Production Readiness Checklist](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/production_ready/#set-uuids-for-all-operators) for details.

If you want to explicitly set UIDs that match the currently auto-generated ones so you can safely evolve the job, you can find the hashed UIDs for each operator by inspecting the running job via the REST API (the vertexId for each operator is its hashed UID). Then you can use those hashed UIDs in combination with `setUidHash()` on those same operators in your code. See [Matching Operator State](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/upgrading/#matching-operator-state) in the Flink documentation.

Comment: okay, is there a way to list all the operator states along with their OperatorID?
And in that case why is it only happening for some of the pipelines, not for all.

Comment: Changes to the topology aren't guaranteed to modify the auto-generated UIDs for all existing state.

Comment: if the newly added pipeline has no edges to any of the previous operator nodes in job graph, will it still be considered as a change in existing pipelines topology.

Comment: It is a change to the job's topology. How this will affect existing UIDs is undefined.

Comment: I am unable to find UID Hash for the operator from Rest API.
when we are hitting /jobs/jobId/vertices/vertexId. i do not see any hashedUid param.
can you please point me in the right direction for this.

Comment: The vertexId is the hashed UID for the operator.

Comment: Post adding UIDs for the operators. we are noticing in logs that offsets are being restored from savepoint for the Kafka consumer operator. however, we are using a windowed Processor for one of the pipelines and noticing that part of the data is getting missed for the time period where the job had failed. (data not getting missed for nonwindowed Processor)
we are using event time for windowing.
could this be happening due to some known issues?

Comment: when we increase the out-of-order events delay in TimeWinows, ie- we increased It to 30min from 4sec, then the events are not getting missed if the application is up within 30min. i can understand this may be due to out-of-order events from kafka. but we are getting no where near the solution since the delay of more than 1 min is infeasible for us also there will be too many live windows which will mean huge infra change for us.

Comment: Somehow your pipeline has become dependent on the passage of processing time -- it's obviously not a pure event time pipeline or else this couldn't be happening. But I can't guess what's causing this. Also, since this is unrelated to this particular question, please create a new question, ideally with a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: i'll create a new question with illustrations for this.

Comment: I have a related question to the above, will vertexId change with a change in job topology even when keeping uid of the operator same.
what will be the impact on state restore for that operator in case it does change ?

Comment: If a UID is provided, then the vertexId is the hash of that UID. The vertexId won't change unless the UID changes.